# Windows Service in Docker container

Tags: docker, windows-services, docker-for-windows

I am looking at possible dockerisation of an application. The application includes multiple Windows Services (.NET WCF). I am yet to try out creating a dockerfile for the windows services. But shall appreciate if someone may provide me with some pointer whether this works well.

Comment: Yes, this will work fine. As long as your service runs in Windows Server Core OS it will most likely run fine inside container too. So I suggest before putting it container learn steps which needs to be taken inside real Server Core OS

Answer (score 18):

In your situation, I'd probably create one image for each Windows Service.

The following Dockerfile works well for me in building a Windows Service into a docker image.

All your service files need to be in the 'Installs' folder of the docker context, plus a copy of the InstallUtils.exe file (from .NET / Visual Studio).

```
# escape=\

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/aspnet:4.7.2-windowsservercore-1709

SHELL ["powershell", "-Command", "$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'; $ProgressPreference = 'SilentlyContinue';"]

COPY ["Installs/", "/Service/"]

WORKDIR "C:/Service/"

RUN "C:/Service/InstallUtil.exe" /LogToConsole=true /ShowCallStack SmartFormsToWorkInjuryReportingService.exe; \
    Set-Service -Name "\"My Windows Service Name\"" -StartupType Automatic; \
    Set-ItemProperty "\"Registry::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\My Windows Service Name\"" -Name AllowRemoteConnection -Value 1

ENTRYPOINT ["powershell"]
CMD Start-Service \""My Windows Service Name\""; \
    Get-EventLog -LogName System -After (Get-Date).AddHours(-1) | Format-List ;\
    $idx = (get-eventlog -LogName System -Newest 1).Index; \
    while ($true) \
    {; \
      start-sleep -Seconds 1; \
      $idx2  = (Get-EventLog -LogName System -newest 1).index; \
      get-eventlog -logname system -newest ($idx2 - $idx) |  sort index | Format-List; \
      $idx = $idx2; \
    }
```

FYI, you can then run the service by:

```
docker run --rm --net=MyNet --platform=windows -p 80:80 --name MyWindowsServiceContainer mywindowsserviceimage
```

Comment: Can InstallUtill.exe be replaced by New-Service?

Comment: Let me ask a basic question - when an app is a candidate to be windows service, is it not evaluated to be a candidate of deamon services (linux version of windows services) and why would we need the Windows Service hosting when we move towards docker container?

Comment: i have used the same snippet and at the time of running it is saying


**docker: Error response from daemon: failed to create endpoint MyWindowsServiceContainer on network nat: failed during hnsCallRawResponse: hnsCall failed in Win32: The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process. (0x20) **
I tried  the following but those did not helped
Stop-Service docker
Stop-service hns
Start-service hns
Start-Service docker
docker network prune